# Stuck with Configuring Varnish

Tags: centos, varnish, whm

I successfully installed varnish etc. via the whm terminal then when it came to Configuring Varnish to listen in on port 80 for incoming http requests.
/etc/sysconfig/varnish

I do not know how to do this. I got help from the get go with the repo to command lines etc and all went off without a hitch until I got to the configure varnish section. Got stuck on step 3.
https://support.qualityunit.com/496090-How-to-install-Varnish-with-CPanel-and-CentOS-to-cache-static-content-on-server

Comment: Hello I have the same problem, did you solve it?

Comment: yes In mt case I removed sudo and just did nano /etc/sysconfig/varnish

Answer (score 0):

from terminal type:

```
sudo nano /etc/sysconfig/varnish
```

The file opens, look for the VARNISH_LISTEN_PORT and change it to 80. Save and close the file and you are done

Comment: Thanks I tried that and it returned file not found. I wound up getting command line help with uninstalling the version I installed and Installing a fresh copy with the one compatible with my server stack., Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: what centos version are you running on?

Comment: it was centos 7.6 thanks for helping me out btw your answered worked back then I just had to drop the sudo and replace it with yum